# How to find location of package?

Tags: r, package

I am building an R package (let's call it "pkg"), and would like to write a function that downloads a file from the internet and saves it in the "inst/extdata" directory in my package's directory.

```
 download_file <- function(link) { 
     path <- ... # path to where "pkg" is stored
                 # something along the lines of ....../pkg
     download.file(link, paste(path, "inst/extdata", "newfile", sep = ""))
 }
```

Could you please help me get the "path"? While developing the package, I can just do "getwd()" -- however, when a user calls my package, her working directory might not be the pkg directory. In which case, how do I get the path to my package's directory?

Comment: Package location can often be read-only. I would advice against doing so in a package.

Comment: Anyway, the function you are looking for is `find.package`.

Comment: `system.file('extdata', package = 'pkg')` but you should probably use `tempfile`/`tempdir` or have the user specify a location. you also will not see the `/inst` folder under `list.files(system.file(package = 'pkg'))`

Comment: thanks, both the above seem to work.

Answer (score 14):

Just run `.libPaths()` and it will show you the filepath to your `library` folder. Inside the library folder you can see all your packages.

Comment: Just a heads up...  .libPaths() will often yield more than one path.

Answer (score 2):

Use `devtools::session_info()`. The fourth column (named `lib`) of the "Packages" output tells you which folder each library was sourced from.